# Get Value of a node when you pass another node value

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a simple XML which looks like this:

```xml
<RealTimeLetter>
  <Customer>
    <RTLtr_Bank>620</RTLtr_Bank>
    <RTLtr_Branch>214</RTLtr_Branch>
    <RTLtr_Loancust>0423436</RTLtr_Loancust>
    <RTLtr_NBR>1001</RTLtr_NBR>
    <RTLtr_LetterNumber>30092</RTLtr_LetterNumber>
    <RTLtr_CustomerAddress1>1234 qwtewret</RTLtr_CustomerAddress1>
    <RTLtr_CustomerAddress2 />
    <RTLtr_CustomerCity>WGEWHG</RTLtr_CustomerCity>
    <RTLtr_CustomerState>CO</RTLtr_CustomerState>
    <RTLtr_CustomerZip>12345</RTLtr_CustomerZip>
    <RTLtr_CoBorrowerName>PYTH SBUH</RTLtr_CoBorrowerName>
    <RTLtr_CustomerName>Alternate1</RTLtr_CustomerName>
    <RTLtr_CustomerSSN>888888888</RTLtr_CustomerSSN>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <RTLtr_Bank>620</RTLtr_Bank>
    <RTLtr_Branch>214</RTLtr_Branch>
    <RTLtr_Loancust>0423437</RTLtr_Loancust>
    <RTLtr_NBR>1001</RTLtr_NBR>
    <RTLtr_LetterNumber>30092</RTLtr_LetterNumber>
    <RTLtr_CustomerAddress1>1234 qwtewret</RTLtr_CustomerAddress1>
    <RTLtr_CustomerAddress2 />
    <RTLtr_CustomerCity>WGEWHG</RTLtr_CustomerCity>
    <RTLtr_CustomerState>CO</RTLtr_CustomerState>
    <RTLtr_CustomerZip>12345</RTLtr_CustomerZip>
    <RTLtr_CoBorrowerName>PYTH SBUH</RTLtr_CoBorrowerName>
    <RTLtr_CustomerName>Alternate2</RTLtr_CustomerName>
    <RTLtr_CustomerSSN>888888888</RTLtr_CustomerSSN>
  </Customer>
</RealTimeLetter>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value of the `<RTLtr_CustomerName>` tag when I give the value of the `<RTLtr_Loancust>` tag.

The script I have is returning `Null` for customer name.

```vb
Dim oFS
Dim sFSpec
Dim objMSXML
Set oFS      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFSpec       = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\Users\ecz560\Documents\CorrespondenceDocs\VBScript\SampleXMLFile.xml")
Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objMSXML.async = False
objMSXML.load sFSpec

If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
    Dim sXPath : sXPath = "RealTimeLetter/Customer[RTLtr_Loancust=""0423436""]"
    Dim ndlX : Set ndlX = objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
    If 0 = ndlX.Length Then
        WScript.Echo sXPath, "failed"
    Else
        Dim ndX
        For Each ndX In ndlX
            WScript.Echo "CustomerName:", ndX.parentNode.GetAttribute("RTLtr_CustomerName")
        Next
    End If
Else
    WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query

```
"RealTimeLetter/Customer[RTLtr_Loancust=""0423436""]"
```

returns a Customer with a specific Loancust/number. You are interested in the RTLtr_CustomerName - a node, not an attribute. So query for

```
"RealTimeLetter/Customer[RTLtr_Loancust=""0423436""]/RTLtr_CustomerName"
```

and work with returned single node. In code:

```
...
    Dim sXPath : sXPath = "RealTimeLetter/Customer[RTLtr_Loancust=""0423436""]/RTLtr_CustomerName"
    Dim ndX : Set ndX = objMSXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
    If ndX Is Nothing Then
       WScript.Echo sXPath, "failed"
    Else
       WScript.Echo "CustomerName:", ndX.text
    End If
...
```

output:

```
cscript 39375295.vbs
CustomerName: Alternate1
```